# Including multiple-select race/ethnicity in statistical models

Tags: regression, demography

I'm performing some survey research that has a strong demographic component. During the survey participants are asked to select any races they identify with, along with a number of other demographic questions.

Most participants select a single race, but there is a meaningful subset that selects more than one. This is particularly true for participants that identify with a significantly underrepresented race (Pacific Islander, for example).

My question is, is there a standard method for handling such multiple-select data? Similar research often groups participants that select two or more races into a general "Two or more" bucket, but that seems like it completely misses who is included in that group. When examining results by race, is there a way to make sure that a participant who selects "Pacific Islander" and "White," for example, informs results for both races?